# Routes values not passing in Html.ActionLink attribute in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I want to pass an id like a string to my action method , I am doing like this

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Nokia Lumia Series", "Mobiles", "Products", new { id = "Lumia" })
```

and here is my action method

```
public ActionResult Mobiles(string name)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

but it is not going on that action and this url is shown in browser tab

```
http://mymobiles.com/Home/Mobiles?Length=8
```

What I am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incorrect overload of `ActionLink`. You should use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx) overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Your code then becomes, I also changed your parameter name to make it more clear:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Nokia Lumia Series", "Mobiles", "Products", new { name = "Lumia" }, null)
```